# Decimal places in Python

Tags: python, algorithm

I am trying to put all the decimal places of `1/n` into a list in Python.

```
def dec(n):

    result = float(1) / n
    while (result >= 1):
        result = result - 1

    while (result != 0):
        result = result * 10
        decimals = int(result)
        yield(decimals)
        result = result - decimals
```

However, when I tried `list(dec(3))`, it doesn't give me a list full of 3s but instead something like `[3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 0, 3, 7, 2]`

How should I fix this?

Comment: Are you aware that a Python list cannot go on forever?

Comment: Also, note that floating point precision is a thing. Floats in a computer are like patients - you do too many operations on them, and they die. (Well, not really, but do read http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html ) If you want to do infinite precision division, just implement the longhand division algorithm yourself, using only integers.

Comment: @user2357112   yes but even so, I would want a way that I can get all 3s and not other numbers. I think I need some kind of trick since my code is not wrong but it doesn't give me the expected result

Comment: A list of finitely many threes would be just as wrong as the list you got. It would only look less wrong.

Comment: @user2357112: `itertools.cycle([3])` is correct... :P (but unprintable, for obvious reasons)

Comment: @user2357112 you do not need an infinite list. In my answer I am explaining why http://stackoverflow.com/a/29426723/1090562 and pointing how it can be solved. This is a purely math problem which has nothing to do with python or any other programming language.

Comment: @SalvadorDali: You don't need a list, and in fact, the OP's code produces a generator, which could go on infinitely if correctly coded. However, *he then calls list on it*. If it weren't for floating-point rounding error, this would have caused Python to attempt to put an infinite sequence of threes into a list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since Python floats are represented in binary, float representations of fractions are not just inexact - decimal approximation are often just as inexact - but inexact in a counter-intuitive way. We are used to approximating a fraction like 1/3 as something like 0.3333333333, or 33333333333/10**10 (assuming 10 significant digits). However, the binary floating-point used by Python represents numbers as fractions with a power-of-two denominator. In this representation, 1/3 is approximated as 6004799503160661/2**54, and the digits in your output come from that fraction.

To calculate the digits of a *decimal* approximation of the fraction 1/3, import the `decimal` module and replace `float(1)` with `decimal.Decimal(1)`.  The [`Decimal` type](https://docs.python.org/2/library/decimal.html) was designed with the express goal of supporting what you're attempting to do here, i.e. getting results that work the same way as pencil-and-paper calculations with algorithms taught in school.

The `Decimal` instance will of course contain a limited number of digits, which are for 1/3 repeated infinitely. To be able to access digits without limit, import `fractions` and use `fractions.Fraction()`. In that case, the sequence produced by the generator will be infinite and you won't be able to convert it to a list, but you will still be able to iterate over it and analyze as much of it as you need.

Comment: I tried "decimal.Decimal(1)" but it said "NameError: global name 'decimal' is not defined"

Comment: @viethaihp291 You need to add `import decimal` near the beginning of your script. (The same goes for `import fractions` if you're going with the fractions.) I've now updated the answer to mention the import.

Comment: thanks for the clarification... but it seems like "decimal" only gives a certain number of decimal places? when I tried to yield 30 times, it gives me an iteration error

Comment: @viethaihp291 The decimal instance can only hold a certain number of decimal places because their full list is infinite. If you need more, you can increase the number of places calculated by changing `getcontext().prec`. If you need unlimited precision, use `fractions.Fraction`, as already stated in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you're using Python 3, since you've got only a single "/". You'll note that float(1)/3*100000000 = 33333333.333333332. This is likely due to the vagaries of binary representation of decimal fractions, because you run out of bits for precision in the width of the float.

So, you'd be better off handling it as a string, and converting that to a list:

```
list(str(float(1)/3))[2:]

['3', '3', '3', '3', '3', '3', '3', '3', '3', '3', '3', '3', '3', '3', '3', '3']
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to present the rational number as a [repeating decimal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Repeating_decimal). And you need to know that:

> Every rational number is either a terminating or repeating decimal.

So you do not need to store all the digits there (non repeating part and repeating part). Another important point is that if you have `m/n` then your repeating part is at maximum `n-1` length.

Because you are basically asking for solution for project Euler 26 task, I will not post it, but rather will give you a [link with some explanation](http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2009/02/25/project-euler-problem-26/).

Answer (score 0):

Floating point arithmetic is necessarily inaccurate. One way to compute the digits exactly is to use the division algorithm you probably learnt at school.

Here's an implementation:

```
def dec(n):
    v = 1
    while v:
        v *= 10
        yield v // n
        v %= n
```

You can test it like this, which shows the first 40 digits for 1/3, 1/5, 1/7 and 1/11.

```
import itertools

for i in [3, 5, 7, 11]:
    print '1/%d = 0.%s' % (i, ''.join(map(str, itertools.islice(dec(i), 40))))
```

The output is:

```
1/3 = 0.3333333333333333333333333333333333333333
1/5 = 0.2
1/7 = 0.1428571428571428571428571428571428571428
1/11 = 0.0909090909090909090909090909090909090909
```